# Android : Open Multiple Chat Window for different users

Tags: android, notifications, android-activity

I want to open multiple chat window by calling single activity multiple times for different chat users. I have tried using notification for opening different chat user activity window but its fails. Opening only single chat window.

Can anyone give me the suggestion how to do it.? or any Idea or alternative way to open Multiple Chat  window..?

Help will be appreciated !!

Comment: There is only one instance of activity running at a time

Comment: yes.. can we create another activity for another user for chat window ??

Answer (score 4):

From what I gather you need to use Android fragments.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Each chat window should be its own fragment but there will be only one activity.